# Array of Char[ ] , find some letter in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, char

I have to do a method that finds if an array of char[ ] like {'d','e','f' } is inside of an other array of char[  ]  like {'a','b','c','d','e','f','x','r'} ... So , i want  that my "x" inside while cicle raises when a letter is found . For example , when my for cycle finds the 1st letter my x= 1 , if for cycle finds the 2nd letter my x = x+1 and so on ... So my x should be equal to the length of the array {'d','e','f'} . Whereas if i have to find an array like {'d','e','f'} in an other array like {'a','d','z','x'} my x is 1 so it is not equal to the length of the array {'d','e','f'},
There is something wrong but I can't find the mistake .

```
public class Stringa 
{
private char[] array1 ;
public int find2(char[]subs)
{
    int x = 1 ;  
    for(int i=0 ; i<this.lunghezza(); i++ ) // lunghezza() find the length
    {
        if(this.array1[i] == subs[0])
        {
            for ( int k = 1 ; k< subs.length ; k++)
            { 
                while (this.array1[i+k]== subs[k]) 
                {
                    x = x+1; ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return x; 
} 
}
```

and the main method is :

```
  public class StringaTester
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      char[] char1 = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','e','r','t'};
      char[] char2 = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','e','r','t'};
      char[] char3 = {'d','e','f'};
      Stringa prova = new Stringa(char1);
      Stringa prova1 = new Stringa(char2);
      Stringa prova3 = new Stringa(char3);

      int l = prova3.lunghezza(); // this find the legth of the substring ( Now 3 )
      if(char1.find2(char3) == l ) // I want to compare 2 char , but is here the error
                                   // if i write  if(prova.find2(char3) == l )
                                   // there aren't any errors
      System.out.println(" substring is inside"); 
      else
      System.out.println("substring is not inside");    
   }
 }
```

this is the error on the terminal when i write if(char1.find2(char3) == l ) :

```
 StringaTester.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
 if(char1.find2(char3) == l )
             ^
 symbol:   method find2(char[])
 location: variable char1 of type char[]
 1 error
```

Comment: Well you're incrementing `x` any time you find a matching letter after the first - you're *not* finding any second letter, therefore `x` has its original value of 1.

Comment: Basically the code appears to be working exactly as I'd expect it to, but your requirements are hard to understand. What would you expect the return value to be for `{'a', 'd', 'z', 'x' }`? What about `{'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'f' }`?

Comment: @MightyPork: Criticizing the original indentation is one thing - but there's no need to do so in an offensive way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Don't think it was offensive. If I saw something like that in a code I have to maintain, I'd be more than angry at the author.

Comment: "There is something wrong but..."  How do you _know_ that there is something wrong?  Do you get an error message?  What is the message?  Also, your example uses variables and functions for which you have not shown us any definition.  It's pretty hard to say what's wrong with the code when we can't see _all_ of the code, and we don't know what the symptom is.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for reply , sorry Its hard to explain for me , I'm italian . Well , I have to create a method that find if a substring is inside a String , so the order of the letter are essential . In main method if x is equals to the length of the substring the substring is inside the string .

Comment: @jameslarge I just edited the code , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[The following implementation](http://ideone.com/AFOWrD) searches for characters of `subs` in `array`:**

```
int find(char[] array, char[] subs)
```

**The method returns the number of characters that were matched.**

It's important to note that the order of the characters in the arrays doesn't matter. For instance, when `array` is declared as  `{ 'f','d','e' }` and `subs` is `{ 'd','e','f' }`, the number of matches returned by this method is **3**.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static int find(char[] array, char[] subs)
    {
        int found = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < subs.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
            {
                if (subs[x] == array[y])
                {
                    found++;

                    // Y is the index of the element found in the original array
                    // we must erase this element so it's not found again.
                    char[] smaller_array = new char[array.length-1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < y)
                            smaller_array[i] = array[i];

                        if (i == y)
                         continue;

                        if (i > y)
                            smaller_array[i-1] = array[i];
                    }

                    array = smaller_array;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        return found;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        char[] sub = { 'd','e','f' };

        char[] array1 = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','x','r' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #1: " + find(array1, sub));

        char[] array2 = { 'g','e','h','i','d','k','x','f' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #2: " + find(array2, sub));

        char[] array3 = { 'd' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #3: " + find(array3, sub));

        char[] array4 = { 'd','d','d' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #4: " + find(array4, sub));

        char[] array5 = { 'd','e','f' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #5: " + find(array5, sub));

        char[] array6 = { 'f','d','e' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #6: " + find(array6, sub));

        char[] array7 = { 'a','b','c','g','h','i','j','k' };
        System.out.println("Number of matches with array #7: " + find(array7, sub));
    }
}
```

**Outputs**:

```
Number of matches with array #1: 3
Number of matches with array #2: 3
Number of matches with array #3: 1
Number of matches with array #4: 1
Number of matches with array #5: 3
Number of matches with array #6: 3
Number of matches with array #7: 0
```

Comment: thanks for reply , i just edited the code . But the order for me is essential , if i have {'d','e','f'} i want to search if "def" if inside an array of char , if there id "fed" it isn't good . In main method i want to compare if my variable x ( found in this case ) is equals to the length od the subs :)

Comment: Great, then just do these small little changes in my code. :)