# Java Algorithms: comparing each *thing* to every other

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I'm creating a program that required me to compare each int item, named **a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j** to every other. I know that, conceptually, the algorithm must look something like this:

- a-b a-c a-d a-e a-f a-g ...
- b-c b-d b-e b-f b-g ...
- c-d c-e c-f c-g ...
- and so on...

My issue is implementing this **without** literally writing everything out. I considered using a 'for' loop, but I have no idea how to refer to the variable names in a 'modular' way.

please let me know if any of this requires more explanation, and thanks in advance!

EDIT: Karlphilip's comment helped me out quite a bit

Comment: Look into arrays. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html arrays)

Comment: You need an array, or a `List`. You then have to have 2 nested loops that both iterate over the array.

Comment: [You might be interested in examining this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27759505/176769)

Comment: Thanks karlphillip, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your items into an array, and use two nested loops to get all pairs, like this:

```
int[] x = new int[] {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
for (int i = 0 ; i != x.length ; i++ ) {
    for (int j = i+1 ; j != x.length ; j++ ) {
        ... // Use x[i] and x[j] here
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure using != x.length is a bad idea... Try substituting with < x.length. In some cases, using != can cause infinite looping.

Comment: @BenKnoble You think that `i` will go from `0` to a value that makes the predicate `i < x.length` false without going through `x.length`?

Comment: @BenKnoble In this particular case this is safe. Generally, I prefer `!=` to `<` following Dijkstra's argument from "Discipline of Programming" (he argued that this lets you use strongest post-condition).

Comment: @PascalCuoq if i >= x.length causes exit and i increments by 1 starting from 0, i will be x.length when the loop terminates, causing i to be recycled by garbage collector. Effectively, never being used as x.length in body of loop. I'm a little confused by the wording of your question though?

Comment: @pbabcdefp consider `for (int i = 0; i != 5; i += 2) {...}`  Obviously bad practice, but infinite.

Comment: @BenKnoble It's pretty good that in this case the loop is infinite, because it exposes author's misunderstanding of his own code. Since he wrote both `!=` and `5`, his expectations where wrong. He'll see this, and replace `!= 5` with `!= 6`.

Comment: I agree. I was more answering @pbabcdefp's question. Of course, if (again, IMHO bad practice) you mess with the control variable in the loop, you might create too many problems that could be easily solved with < or <=. However, I respect your preference and reasons

Comment: @BenKnoble I deleted my comment about `Integer` because it was wrong. If `i` is of type `Integer` then `i != x.length` will do the comparison using primitives. But if we're allowed to completely change the rules you could get an infinite loop using `<` as well. `for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i += 2)`

Comment: Loops are problematic if not checked carefully. That's something we can all agree on :P

Answer (score 0):

To compare each item with every other item in the "array" or "list" of numbers, you would need to have one for loop nested within the other.